# Reading Cell from CSV, trying to truncate the code

Tags: python, csv

So I am reading two cells out of a CSV file to compare them against each other

```
import csv

portfolio = csv.reader(open(r"c:\testing.csv", "rb"))
APP_TYPE = []

for app_data in portfolio:
    APP_TYPE.append(app_data[1])

portfolio1 = csv.reader(open(r"c:\testing.csv", "rb"))
APP_TYPE1 = []

for app_data1 in portfolio1:
    APP_TYPE1.append(app_data1[2])

if APP_TYPE1[1] == 'CLIENT' and APP_TYPE[1] == 'A1':
    print "yes"
```

And I have tried a few times because I feel like this is a terrible way of doing it, what is a better approach to trimming down the fat so to speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *once*, use the `csv.reader()` object as an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable), skip the first row using the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), then read the second using `next()` again:

```
import csv

with open(r"c:\testing.csv", "rb") as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    next(reader, None)   # skip first row
    row = next(reader)
    if row[1] == 'A1' and row[2] == 'CLIENT':
        print "yes"
```

This reads no more that the first two rows from the file, in *one* step. The `with` statement uses the open file object as a context manager, which means it'll be closed automatically when the reading operations are done.

You could also use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to slice out the 1 row:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open(r"c:\testing.csv", "rb") as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    for row in islice(reader, 1, 2):  # skip first, only read second row
        if row[1] == 'A1' and row[2] == 'CLIENT':
            print "yes"
```

For a single skip + single read, I usually stick to `next()` anyway, but when skipping more than one row `islice()` is invaluable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, +1 for `itertools`. I hope slices of iterables will become syntax someday.

Answer (score 1):

Improvements:

- Use `with` (closes the file for you at the end of the block)
- Read once
- Only read first two lines

---

```
import csv

with open(r'c:\testing.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip first line
    row = next(reader)
    if row[1] == 'A1' and row[2] == 'CLIENT':
        print 'yes'
```

And I made the string quoting consistent, for readability.

Comment: I always add `None` as a second argument to the `next(reader)` call when skipping the header; that way you don't get a `StopIteration` exception for an empty file *just* because you wanted to skip the header.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, good idea, but you will get an error (in this case) anyway if it is empty.

Comment: Sure, but it's a force of habit with a reason. :-)

Comment: thanks for the help paul, just started learning, appreciate it.